# Neo4j unable to delete multiple nodes. I get a transaction failure exception

Tags: neo4j, nodes

I am trying to remove around 40,000 nodes no longer needed via the webadmin console, but I am getting the following message:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ start n=node:node_auto_index(tipo="not_needed")  DELETE n;
==> TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction
```

Do anybody know if there is a way around this using the console?

Answer (score 5):

This is probably because the nodes are connected still. You'll need to delete their relationships as well. Something like:

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(tipo="not_needed") 
MATCH n-[r?]-() 
DELETE n,r;
```

Comment: for some reason I did not receive a notification of your response :(

But... at some point I think I deleted all relationships. In any case, I will try again with your suggestion. Thanks a lot.